# Is there a connection between serious injuries/deaths in boxing and having one's father in one's corner?

Tags: statistics, training, injuries, boxing

In the commentary on the tragic 2005 Leavander Johnson/Jesus Chavez fight, which claimed the life of Leavander Johnson, [commentator Jim Lampley said that there are two things that seem to be "constant" in recent fights where a boxer was seriously - sometimes permanently - injured](https://youtu.be/F4yeA1uHiXI?t=43m49s):

> In the recent history of the sport, when you look at fights where one fighter has been badly, sometimes permanently damaged, two constants seem to be part of the formula. Number one, the opponent who is doing the damage is a hard  hitter, but not a big enough hitter to put the opponent away. **Number two, the guy who is getting worked over has his father in the corner as his trainer, constantly sending him back to take more punishment.**

The announcer actually said, in the 10th round, that he hoped that wouldn't be the case for Leavander Johnson, and the fight was stopped early in the 11th round;  however, Leavander Johnson died 5 days later from his injuries.

A little research on my part turned up [an earlier article from the LA Times](http://articles.latimes.com/1995-10-31/sports/sp-63078_1_california-ring), which listed other fighters who were killed in their bouts and had their fathers in their corners:

Johnny Owens (1980)
Kiko Bejines (1983)
Rico Velazquez (1988)
Jimmy Garcia (1995)
Fernie Morales (1991)<sup>1</sup>

More recently, in 2009, [Francisco "Paco" Rodriguez](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2009-11-24/news/0911230663_1_chicago-boxer-fatal-boxing-community) was killed in the ring, with his father in the corner.

[Here's a slightly more thorough list](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17osnLRiUHzBSsWIgkNRt9tFI_TgY6nBF4lBPbbZbDwg/edit?usp=sharing) of boxers who were killed or seriously injured in the ring since 1980 with their fathers in their corners.

One of the four main sanctioning bodies in professional boxing, the World Boxing Council (or WBC) [actually has rules on the books](http://www.nydailynews.com/sports/more-sports/world-boxing-council-daddy-issues-article-1.418597) prohibiting fathers from their son's corners because of the alleged correlation:

> Dr. Paul Wallace, chairman of the WBC's medical advisory board, said that a study in California backed up the WBC's rule.
>
> "The most common factor out of all the fatalities that had happened, was having fathers in the corner," he said of the study. "Now, that's not something that's a medical issue, but it's something that's clearly an association."
>   -  [NY Daily News](http://www.nydailynews.com/sports/more-sports/world-boxing-council-daddy-issues-article-1.418597)

The State Athletic Commissions of California and Nevada, which are responsible for regulating safety in the ring, also believe the link exists:

> Prompted by Garcia's death [in May 1995], the California Athletic Commission conducted a preliminary inquiry into California ring injuries since 1980.
>
> It was discovered that **four of the seven most serious head injuries reviewed--including all three California ring-related deaths--involved fighters whose fathers worked their corners**.
>
> **Richard DeCuir, the commission's executive director**, admits the examination was not scientific--"The numbers have not been scrubbed," he said--yet **the findings struck him as alarmingly disproportionate**, given the best estimates that only 5%-7% of professional fighters are trained by relatives.
>
> DeCuir cannot speak to the specifics of each case nor is it his intention to implicate families that have already suffered, yet **he suspects there is a correlation between ring injuries and relatives.**
>
> **"I think we all pretty much believe that," DeCuir said.**
>
> **DeCuir sent his information to Marc Ratner, head of the Nevada State Commission**, who is still grappling with Garcia's death in May.
>
> "It's something we have no choice but to address, because **it is more than coincidence," Ratner said of the father-son issue.**
>   - [LA Times](http://articles.latimes.com/1995-10-31/sports/sp-63078_1_california-ring)

The quotes above make it clear that the issue has been investigated at least once, but the source "admits the examination was not scientific--"The numbers have not been scrubbed." Thus, we can't resolve the issue with certainty unless someone has done a more scientific study.

**Has there ever been a serious analysis into the possible correlation between permanent injury/deaths in the ring, and having one's father in the corner?  Do we know if there is actually a statistical correlation between these two factors?**

---

<sup>1</sup> *Fortunately, Morales actually survived, but suffered a blood clot in his brain, had to have emergency brain surgery to remove it, and never fought again.  Sadly, all the others on the list died from their injuries.*

Comment: I'm reopening this question (with 3 additional reopen votes). There was only one close vote on this question (before the moderator's bound vote, which placed this question on hold), so I'm not sure where "6 close votes" came from. Any further discussion about this question's on-topic designation should be addressed in meta.

Comment: @Rathony The answer is either "yes, here are the studies and a quick synopsis of said studies" or "no, this is speculation and coincidence due to bias and ignorance toward the overall number of deaths (which you have been adamantly stating)." In either case, it can be definitive in two or three paragraphs, maybe less.

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ There were 4 close votes (one was mine) and they aged away. I voted to close it again (which is the 5th vote) and a moderator single-hammered it (6th). Now, I don't know whether there will be a definitive answer or not, but yes, answers to so so many closed Qs on Sports SE could be yes or no. The most important thing is whether it is actually related with Sports and how? How does some boxers injuries and death have to do with their fathers' presence? What does the OP want from this question? One SE site which will more than welcome this kind of conspiracy theory, Skeptics SE.

Comment: Let's say there is a connection. So what? Are you going to ban all fathers to coach or sit on the front row in a boxing game? As you know, if fathers sit on the front row, a boxer can hear them. Does his father have to be a coach to yell at the box and say **keep fighting until you die**? Do you have any case where a boxer got killed because his girlfriend or mother was yelling? How can this question be helpful to current and future users? I strongly doubt it.

Comment: @Rathony - we are here to request and provide information, not determine the appropriate regulations for professional sports.  I want what everyone on SE wants when they post a question:  an answer. You're ranting about the practicality of boxing organizations making policy decisions based on any potential information, but that is irrelevant and beyond the scope of the site. I just want to know if the information exists.  The answer is either "apparently not" or "yes, here it is". Just move on. This is a perfectly valid, answerable question.

Comment: The question isn't opinion based, theoretical, or too broad. It is "Are there studies on this aspect of professional boxing?" It has nothing to do with superstitions, rumors, myths, or fallacies. I'm simply asking if there is statistical information about injuries and deaths in a professional sport.

Comment: I am not ranting about anything. You answered the Q yourself. Yes, there is a connection if you believe in superstition. No, there is no connection if you don't believe in superstition. Does it answer your question?

Comment: @Rathony - read the quote in the question again.   'Richard DeCuir, the commission's executive director, admits the examination was not scientific--"The numbers have not been scrubbed"''  I am asking if there is firm evidence. A scientific study. Seven years have passed since that article was written. Plenty of time for a scholarly investigation.

Comment: I recommended a better site for you to ask this conspiracy theory and I am done. Good luck.

Comment: I feel like you don't know what "conspiracy" means.

Comment: The fact that there has been some time does not at all suggest another study would have been done, especially when it's a topic so niche that only 25 data have been collected in the last 36 years.

Comment: @Nij -  I'm well aware that time passing doesn't mean more studies HAVE been done.  It means they COULD have been done. Here's the raw data for recorded fatalities https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e7iWW3KLuVYfQjN_MOK3a9M42Ht_ACIZVa3Tf5n_Z5o/edit#gid=2032432571  The problem is that the records don't mention who was in the corner

Comment: The most upvoted question without an answer needs some more attention! Let's see if a bounty helps getting some canonical answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because...I agree, this is the stuff of conspiracy theories, and in no objective way can be answered with anything Sports-related.  Skeptics SE it should be.