# Which boxers were killed or seriously injured in the ring with their father in their corner since 1980?

Tags: training, injuries, boxing

I'm trying to get more data in relation to the issue that led me to ask [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13588/is-there-a-connection-between-serious-injuries-deaths-in-boxing-and-having-ones).

So far, I have the following:

#### Killed with father in the corner:

- Jimmy Garcia (1995)
- Johnny Owen [real name Johnny Owens]  (1980)
- Francisco “Kiko” Bejines (1983)
- Rico Velazquez (1988)
- Leavander Johnson (2005)
- Francisco “Paco” Rodriguez (2009)
- Braydon Smith (2015)
- Bobby Tomasello (2000)
- David “El Terry” Acevedo (2015)
- Benjamin Flores (2009)

#### Seriously injured with father in the corner:

- [Gabriel Rosado](http://deadspin.com/5977443/i-gotta-stop-it-your-sons-gonna-die-fight-finally-called-because-gabriel-rosado-couldnt-see-anything-through-his-blood-covered-face) (2013)
- Fernie Morales (1991)
- Jason Rushton (2009)
- Prichard Colon (2015)

I'm looking for any more cases in which a boxer was seriously or fatally injured  during a fight in which his father was in his corner, from 1980 to the present.

Comment: I think it would be appropriate to get the number of all boxing deaths, and compare the subset -- boxers who died in the ring with their father in their corner  (ie, out of x boxers who have died  in the ring since 1980, y boxers had their father in their corner). Thoughts?

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ I already have the "All boxing deaths" data.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e7iWW3KLuVYfQjN_MOK3a9M42Ht_ACIZVa3Tf5n_Z5o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: 1) Amazing spreadsheet. Where did you get that from? 2) 10 boxer deaths out of 319 since 1980 is hardly an epidemic, but an interesting occurrence nonetheless considering it has happened a double-digit number of times.

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ I got in touch with the guy who runs the [Manuel Velazquez Boxing Fatality Collection](http://ejmas.com/jcs/velazquez/) and asked him for his raw data;  he was nice enough to share it with me.  And there are only 10 deaths and 4 serious injuries on my list so far, but that's mostly because I haven't gone through the data methodically and checked every name on the list since 1980.  The real figures could be FAR higher.

Answer (score 3):

Starting a community wiki based on your findings. Anyone is free to add onto these lists.

#### Killed with father in the corner:

- Jimmy Garcia (1995)
- Johnny Owen [real name Johnny Owens]  (1980)
- Francisco “Kiko” Bejines (1983)
- Rico Velazquez (1988)
- Leavander Johnson (2005)
- Francisco “Paco” Rodriguez (2009)
- Braydon Smith (2015)
- Bobby Tomasello (2000)
- David “El Terry” Acevedo (2015)
- Benjamin Flores (2009)

#### Seriously injured with father in the corner:

- [Gabriel Rosado](http://deadspin.com/5977443/i-gotta-stop-it-your-sons-gonna-die-fight-finally-called-because-gabriel-rosado-couldnt-see-anything-through-his-blood-covered-face) (2013)
- Fernie Morales (1991)
- Jason Rushton (2009)
- Prichard Colon (2015)